# Change value of table when double click

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a table that looks like this :

```
<table style="width:100%">
   <tr>
      <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;"> </th>
      <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;">Senin</th>
      <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;">Selasa</th>
      <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;">Rabu</th>
      <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;">Kamis</th>
      <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;">Jumat</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;">06.00 - 07.00</th>
      <?php if ($senin06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $senin06; "</td>"; ?>
      <?php if ($selasa06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $selasa06; "</td>"; ?>
      <?php if ($rabu06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $rabu06; "</td>"; ?>
      <?php if ($kamis06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $kamis06; "</td>"; ?>
      <?php if ($jumat06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $jumat06; "</td>"; ?>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;">07.00 - 08.00</th>
      <?php if ($senin07 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $senin07; "</td>"; ?>
      <?php if ($selasa07 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $selasa07; "</td>"; ?>
      <?php if ($rabu07 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $rabu07; "</td>"; ?>
      <?php if ($kamis07 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $kamis07; "</td>"; ?>
      <?php if ($jumat07 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $jumat07; "</td>"; ?>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want to change the value inside the td element when the user double click on it. The table contain variables that connected to `PHPMyAdmin`, any idea how to do it?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. 
So it's been a minute since I used `PHPMyAdmin`, but IIRC it's just a GUI for a MySQL database. I don't know of ways to use PHPMyAdmin to manage the DB programmatically via API calls. 

Here you would need to add a JavaScript click handler to the table (or each `<td>`) that updates the values and fires some sort of data transmission operation to update the DB via PHP. 

Also, there's a lot of noise in this example. It would be helpful if you reduced the code to a minimal reproducible example and omitted irrelevant information (such as inline styling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is horrible... but I think you may a beginner.

So, here is my answer:

```php
<?php
$senin06 = "-";
$selasa06 = "-";
$rabu06 = "-";
$kamis06 = "-";
$jumat06 = "X";
?>

<style>
  td, th {
    text-align: center;
    max-width:150px; 
    min-width:150px; 
    width:150px;
  }
</style>

<table id="editable" style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <th>Senin</th>
            <th>Selasa</th>
            <th>Rabu</th>
            <th>Kamis</th>
            <th>Jumat</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>06.00 - 07.00</th>
            <?php if ($senin06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td class='$kelas'><span>"; echo $senin06; "</span></td>"; 
            if ($selasa06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td class='$kelas'><span>"; echo $selasa06; "</span></td>"; 
            if ($rabu06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td class='$kelas'><span>"; echo $rabu06; "</span></td>"; 
            if ($kamis06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td class='$kelas'><span>"; echo $kamis06; "</span></td>"; 
            if ($jumat06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
            echo "<td class='$kelas'><span>"; echo $jumat06; "</span></td>"; ?>
          </tr>
</table>

<script>
  // insert hidden input to each td element.
  document.querySelectorAll("table#editable td").forEach(function(each){
    let value = each.querySelector("span").innerText;
    each.innerHTML += `<input type="text" value="${value}" style="display: none;">`;

    // when user double click, hidden span and display input.
    each.addEventListener("dblclick", function(event){
      each.querySelector("span").style.display = "none";
      each.querySelector("input").style.display = "initial";
      each.querySelector("input").focus();
    });

    // when user leave input (blur), hidden input and display span, and change span's innerText.
    each.querySelector("input").addEventListener("blur", function(event){
      each.querySelector("input").style.display = "none";
      each.querySelector("span").style.display = "initial";

      let value = each.querySelector("input").value;
      each.querySelector("span").innerText = value;
    });
  });
</script>
```

NOTE:

1. Please try to avoid inline-style, it will overwrite all css files.
2. I add a span tag let JavaScript can easily identify what is original word.
3. This code still have ton of parts can be better.
4. This is not save changed data immediately, recommended you make a button for save all data to upload database.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. I didn't think about the <span> thing. Also, I used the inline style because, that's just half the table, I want to use different size in one table.

Comment: Hey, so I encountered a problem on the save button. Do I need to use AJAX?

Comment: If you want save data when you changed, yeah, you need ajax. But if you want easier to develop, you can just make a button to save all data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got it right, but I think you want this
Use "ondblclick" Event

```
    <?php 
        $senin06 = "-";
        $selasa06 = "-";
        $rabu06 = "-";
        $kamis06 = "-";
        $jumat06 = "-";
        $senin07 = "-";
        $selasa07 = "-";
        $rabu07 = "-";
        $kamis07 = "-";
        $jumat07 = "-";
    ?>

    <style type="text/css">
        td { border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; }
    </style>

    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;"> </th>
        <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;">Senin</th>
        <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;">Selasa</th>
        <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;">Rabu</th>
        <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;">Kamis</th>
        <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;">Jumat</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;">06.00 - 07.00</th>
        <?php if ($senin06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
        echo "<td ondblclick='editTD(this)' style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $senin06; "</td>"; ?>
        <?php if ($selasa06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
        echo "<td ondblclick='editTD(this)' style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $selasa06; "</td>"; ?>
        <?php if ($rabu06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
        echo "<td ondblclick='editTD(this)' style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $rabu06; "</td>"; ?>
        <?php if ($kamis06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
        echo "<td ondblclick='editTD(this)' style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $kamis06; "</td>"; ?>
        <?php if ($jumat06 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
        echo "<td ondblclick='editTD(this)' style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $jumat06; "</td>"; ?>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;">07.00 - 08.00</th>
        <?php if ($senin07 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
        echo "<td ondblclick='editTD(this)' style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $senin07; "</td>"; ?>
        <?php if ($selasa07 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
        echo "<td ondblclick='editTD(this)' style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $selasa07; "</td>"; ?>
        <?php if ($rabu07 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
        echo "<td ondblclick='editTD(this)' style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $rabu07; "</td>"; ?>
        <?php if ($kamis07 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
        echo "<td ondblclick='editTD(this)' style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $kamis07; "</td>"; ?>
        <?php if ($jumat07 == "-") {$kelas = "kosong";} else {$kelas = "biasa";}
        echo "<td ondblclick='editTD(this)' style='max-width:150px; min-width:150px; width:150px;' class='$kelas'>"; echo $jumat07; "</td>"; ?>
      </tr>
    </table>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function editTD(clicked) {
          var x = clicked.getAttribute("class");
          if (x === "kosong") {
            clicked.innerHTML = "biasa"
            clicked.setAttribute("class", "biasa"); 
          } else {
            clicked.innerHTML = "kosong"
            clicked.setAttribute("class", "kosong"); 
          }
        }
    </script>
```